# How to insert Value from drop-down value to database table by comparing with option value in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

### Table of database

```
Table #1- april
id  | month  | rent
-------------------
1   |  null  | null
```

---

```
Table #2- may

id  |  month  |rent
-------------------
1   |  null  | null
```

---

### HTML  form codes

```
<form  name="SelectPeriod" method="post" action="monthselect.php">
Select month:
<select name="month">
    <?php
    $monthName = array("JANUARY", " FEBRUARY", " MARCH", " APRIL", " MAY", " JUNE", " JULY", " AUGUST", " SEPTEMBER", " OCTOBER ", " NOVEMBER ", " DECEMBER ");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($monthName); $i++) {
        $mn = 1 + $i;
        if ($mn == date("m")) {
            echo "<option selected value = " . $mn . ">" . $monthName[$i] . "</option> \n";
        } else {
            echo "<option value = " . $mn . ">" . $monthName[$i] . "</option> \n";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="text" name="rent" value="" placeholder="Enter rent input"/>
<input type="submit" name="selectmonth" value=" Go" /></form>
```

### And here php code for insert into

```
<?php   if (isset($_POST['selectmonth'])) {
$month=$_POST['month'];//name of drop-down
$rent = $_POST['rent'];//name of textbox
if ($month == 'APRIL') { //<---here is the problem how to compare with table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO april (month, rent) VALUES('$month','$rent')";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result === TRUE) {
        echo 'Successfully Inserted';
    } else {
        echo 'There is a problem';
    }
} elseif ($month == 'MAY') {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO may (month, rent) VALUES('$month','$rent')";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result === TRUE) {
        echo 'Successfully Inserted';
    } else {
        echo 'There is a problem';
    }
}}?>
```

I want know how to insert in to specific month table with compare to drop-down month value april and may. or Any alternate solution ?

Answer (score 0):

With the below code you don't need to compare any month with the help of month id you can insert data to any table you want but i'm curious to know why you need seprate table of each month instead you can manage all data month wise in single table?

i'm just creating an associative array so when we get month id we can get the table name from it and so on we can run our query without comparing anything.

```
$monthName = array(1 => "JANUARY", 2 => "FEBRUARY", 3 => "MARCH", 4 => "APRIL", 5 => "MAY", 6 => "JUNE", 7 => "JULY", 8 => "AUGUST", 9 => "SEPTEMBER", 10 => "OCTOBER ", 11 => "NOVEMBER ", 12 => "DECEMBER");    
<?php   if (isset($_POST['selectmonth'])) {
    $month=$_POST['month'];//name of drop-down
    $rent = $_POST['rent'];//name of textbox
    $table_name_where_data_to_insert = $monthName[$month];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $table_name_where_data_to_insert . " (month, rent) VALUES('$month','$rent')";
        $result = $con->query($sql);
        if ($result === TRUE) {
            echo 'Successfully Inserted';
        } else {
            echo 'There is a problem';
        }
    }}?>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But with your code data is submitting in only april table not in may table. please have a look in your code

Answer (score 0):

You should set the name of the month in the option values which will be same as your table name. Then you can run your insert query based on the month selected and directly take the name of the table as the option selected.

Use the name of the month instead of month index. Use April instead of 4 in option value. You can use this:

```
echo "<option value = " . $monthName[$i] . ">" . $monthName[$i] . "</option> \n"; }
```

Comment: Thanks. !.  But i have already did that. i am designing with system month and year.

Comment: I can't find a mention of year in your question. Could you please give some more information about it?

Comment: it is just month only. I am making a rental project based on that i want to submit rent of each candidate in every month.

Comment: I'm saying, in the below line, use the name of the month instead of month index.
Use April instead of 4 in option value.
echo "<option value = " . $mn . ">" . $monthName[$i] . "</option> \n"; }